# ui router loading all views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've got my ui router working the way I want... ultimately, but it seems like when it loads a new view...it also temorarily loads all the other views in that state, and then quickley erases them.  What gives?

EDIT: this is definetely the case.  I can see a GET request in firebug for both views every time I click a new link.

```
WriterSarah.config ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->
  $urlRouterProvider
    .when('/', 'about')
    .otherwise('/')

  $stateProvider

  .state('app' ,
    url: '/'
    views:{
      'public':{
        templateUrl: '/assets/cats/cat_index.html.slim'
        controller: 'CatsController'
      }
      'edit':{
        templateUrl: '/assets/cats/edit/cat_index_edit.html.slim'
        controller: 'CatsController'
      }
    }
  )


  .state('app.cat',
    url: "category/:title"
    views:{
      'public':{
        templateUrl: '/assets/cats/cat_show.html.slim'
        controller: 'CatsController'
      }
      'edit':{
        templateUrl: '/assets/cats/edit/cat_show_edit.html.slim'
        controller: 'CatsController'
      }
    }

  )

  .state('app.about',
    url: "about"
    views:{
      'public':{
        templateUrl: '/assets/cats/cat_about.html.slim'
        controller: 'CatsController'
      }
      'edit':{
        templateUrl: '/assets/cats/edit/cat_about_edit.html.slim'
        controller: 'CatsController'
      }
    }
  )

  .state('app.contact',
    url: "contact"
    views:{
      'public':{
        templateUrl: '/assets/cats/cat_contact.html.slim'
        controller: 'CatsController'
      }
      'edit':{
        templateUrl: '/assets/cats/edit/cat_contact_edit.html.slim'
        controller: 'CatsController'
      }
    }
  )
```

in my html, if I have:

```
<div ui-view="edit"></div>
```

it will quickley load ui-view="public" for a split second, and then load "edit" right after that.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-cloak` may be the solution, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

> The `ngCloak` directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.